# How to substract a String time from the current date?

Tags: php

I'd like to substract a specified time from the current date. I don't know why but it says that my date (which I want to sub) is a string. How can I convert it to a format which if I substract the current time from, I get the days left value.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have your date in a variable named `$dateToSubtract`, you can use PHP's [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/strtotime) to convert it to a timestamp:

```
$timestamp = strtotime($dateToSubtract);
```

To use in finding the difference between "now" and the specified date:

```
$date = time() - strtotime($dateToSubtract);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the dateDiff function specified [HERE](http://www.ozzu.com/programming-forum/subtracting-date-from-another-t29111.html).
It's the most effective thing I have found.

Comment: Thank you. After that, how can I count those days which remain? Because I'd actually want to create count down.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "count those days which remain" ?

Comment: Oh sorry I've miswritten. I'd like to substract the CURRENT time FROM date in the vaiable. So there will remain some time, right? I'd like to make it days.

Comment: It would be great, but when I want to use it, it always says the following: "Warning: date_diff() expects parameter 1 to be DateTime, string given in"

Answer (score 1):

Suppose `$num_of_days` is the no. of days you want to subtract from current day.

```
 $new_date =  date('Ymd', strtotime(date('Ymd', strtotime(date('Ymd') . " -  ".$num_of_days."days"))));
```

`$new_date` would be in date Ymd format. If you want it in time,

```
 $new_time = strtotime(date('Ymd', strtotime(date('Ymd') . " -  ".$num_of_days."days")));
```

Comment: Thank you. After that, how can I count those days which remain? Because I'd actually want to create count down.

Comment: remain from what? isn't the no. of days that need to be subtracted (in my example `$num_of_days`) the difference, you are looking for?

Comment: Oh sorry I've miswritten. I'd like to substract the CURRENT time FROM date in the vaiable. So there will remain some time, right? I'd like to make it days.

Answer (score 0):

[`strtotime`](http://php.net/strtotime), literally named "string to time", should be what you're looking for.